# animate speedometer needle using only CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to animate a speedometer - going from left (green) to right (red). Once the animation has run am I trying also trying to make the needle loop at the end/red area of the barometer. How can I achieve this using only CSS?

```css
#speedometer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#speedometer .barometer {
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/GAZ.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#speedometer .needle {
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/GBP.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 999999;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="speedometer">
  <span class="barometer"></span>
  <span class="needle"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first adjust the dimension of the needle element and the `transform-origin` then simply use a rotation:

```css
#speedometer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#speedometer .barometer {
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/GAZ.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#speedometer .needle {
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/GBP.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 999999;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  animation:
  change 3s linear,
    loop 1s linear 3s infinite alternate;
  transform-origin:50% calc(100% - 8px) ;
}
@keyframes change {
  0% {
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(90deg);
  }
}
@keyframes loop {
  0% {
    transform:rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(70deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="speedometer">
  <span class="barometer"></span>
  <span class="needle"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Temani Afif That works. However, the needle dies once it hits the end position. How can I make the needle loop only at the end/red area of the barometer?

Comment: @TobiasM it's not like I did? how you want the looping to be?

Comment: Oh, I see. @Temani Afif Sorry for not being clear enough in my question. Looking for a continuous loop in the red area of the barometer. Going from the start of the red area to the end. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @TobiasM not sure if  undestand well. based on my code what is wrong? The needle goes to the end then keep looping in the red area, no?

Comment: Never mind. Your code is perfect! Something was wrong with my code editor. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you @TemaniAfif. This is exactly what I needed without the loop. Upvoted your answer again. I wish I could upvote more :)